# Loop to remove inverted commas (") in a dataset in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, ubuntu, while-loop

I would like to find a way to use an iterative loop (for or while) to remove quotes (") from a dataset like the following:

```
",great britain,"America"
```

I know that there is the following way to remove them, which is actually more efficient, but it is important that it is an iterative statement in bash

```
sed -i -e 's/"//g' file.csv
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while read -r` to read the lines. Use Parameter Expansion to remove the double quotes.

```
while read -r line ; do printf '%s\n' "${line//\"}" ; done < input
```

Comment: Is there a way to send the lines without " to another file without doing printf?

Comment: @oshiono: I don't understand. What's wrong with `printf`? Use redirection `> output_file` to redirect the output.